# Reboot via `crontab` does not work on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4, cron, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I'm trying to configure a periodic reboot of my Raspberry Pi 4 via `crontab` (reboot every Wednesday and Sunday at midnight). However, the Raspi actually never reboots.

Here's a summary of my different attempts:

- `sudo crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN reboot` → ❌ no reboot
- `sudo crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN sudo reboot` → ❌ no reboot
- `crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN reboot` → ❌ no reboot
- `crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN sudo reboot` → ❌ no reboot
- `sudo crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN shutdown -r now` → ❌ no reboot

Since none of the previous attempts worked, I tried the following:

- `sudo crontab -e` → `0/10 * * * * reboot >> /home/myUser/temp/reboot.log` → ❌ no reboot and `/home/myUser/temp/reboot.log` does not exist

The output of `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -w 'cron'` over the course of three hours is:

```
Nov  9 14:28:01 myRaspi cron[405]: (myUser) RELOAD (crontabs/myUser)
Nov  9 14:28:01 myRaspi cron[405]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Nov  9 15:17:01 myRaspi CRON[15534]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov  9 16:17:01 myRaspi CRON[27095]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
```

Here's the output of `cat /etc/os-release`:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the syntax right on the first entry:

- `sudo crontab -e` → `0 0 * * WED,SUN reboot` → ❌ no reboot

I confirmed that with [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_0_*_*_WED,SUN), and in `man 5 crontab`.

The thing you have missed is in the $PATH for `cron`. `cron`'s PATH is `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin`, and `reboot` is at `/usr/sbin/reboot`.

Consequently, if you'll change the `root crontab` entry as follows, it should work:

```
0 0 * * WED,SUN /usr/sbin/reboot
```

Also, you can generally help yourself out with `crontab` entries by adding some *re-direction* to capture the `stderr` and `stdout` streams to a file (because `cron` cannot know how to reach your terminal):

```
0 0 * * WED,SUN /usr/sbin/reboot >> /home/pi/cronlog 2>&1
```

Comment: Price for the tech hero of the day goes to you :) it works, thank you very much! Just for my understanding: the file `cronlog` does not contain any content after the reboot - should it?

Comment: Yes. Cron runs in a restricted environment and there is no $PATH to search for executables specified by name only.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how that answers my question why the log file `cronlog` that Seamus suggested is empty?

Comment: @mu88: Glad it helped. If `/home/pi/cronlog` does not contain any content, that is because your command (`/usr/sbin/reboot`) did not generate any... but of course it wouldn't if the command were successful. But that's not *generally* true for all commands. The point is that this redirection ( `>>` ) should always be used if you need to capture any output from your command. You might actually try the redirection on some of the jobs you tried that did not work to see what it has to say :)

Comment: never use a sudo crontab. Had a problem with it in past, a normal crontab -e works just fine.

Comment: @dingo27mobile: sez `"never use a sudo crontab"`.  That is ***so*** incorrect. Maybe it's how **you** use it???

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
0 0 * * 0,3 /sbin/reboot
```

in the crontab for root.

As for what you are doing:

```
sudo crontab -e → 0 0 * * WED,SUN reboot → ❌ no reboot
```

You're editing the crontab for root and put the `reboot` in there.

```
sudo crontab -e → 0 0 * * WED,SUN sudo reboot → ❌ no reboot
```

You're editing the crontab for root and put in `sudo reboot`. Because the cronjobs get executed by root, the `sudo` is unnecessary.

```
crontab -e → 0 0 * * WED,SUN reboot → ❌ no reboot
```

You're editing the user's crontab an put in a `reboot`. The ordinary user is not allowed to reboot and therefore, this will fail.

```
crontab -e → 0 0 * * WED,SUN sudo reboot → ❌ no reboot
```

You put a `sudo reboot` in the user's crontab. If the user is alllowed to `sudo reboot`, then this might work